# How do I use the value from one publisher in a request for a dataTaskPublisher in the same chain?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm new to combine, and trying to figure out how to chain Publishers. I have one publisher that returns a string value that I would like to use to build a URLRequest, which is in turn being passed to a DataTaskPublisher. Any help with the correct syntax would be appreciated!

sample code:

```
struct ResultObject: Decodable {}

func getValueKey() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    return Just("Test")
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func performSearch(_ searchTerm: String) -> AnyPublisher<[ResultObject], Error> {
    return getValueKey().flatMap { valueKey in
        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.test.com/\(valueKey)")!)
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [ResultObject].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher() /* Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context */
}
```

note: I'm very unsure about the position of the last `eraseToAnyPublisher`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you gave `flatMap`'s formal parameter the name `valueKey`, but later you tried to reference it using the name `value`. These need to match.

Second, Swift cannot deduce the return type of a multi-statement function like the closure you're passing to `flatMap`. (It **can** deduce the argument type as the `Output` type of the publisher returned by `getValueKey`.)

There are two general ways to fix this problem:

- Change your code so the closure only contains a single statement, **or**
- Explicitly give the return type.

One way to rewrite it as a single statement is to use a `map` operator to convert the incoming `String` to a `URLRequest`, like this:

```
func performSearch(_ searchTerm: String) -> AnyPublisher<[ResultObject], Error> {
    return getValueKey()
        .map { URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.test.com/\($0)")!) }
        .flatMap {
            return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
                .map { $0.data }
                .decode(type: [ResultObject].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

We could also reduce the nesting here by using `mapError` to convert `URLError` to `Error` and then moving the other operators outside of the `flatMap`:

```
func performSearch(_ searchTerm: String) -> AnyPublisher<[ResultObject], Error> {
    return getValueKey()
        .map { URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.test.com/\($0)")!) }
        .flatMap { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0).mapError { $0 as Error } }
        .map { $0.data }
        .decode(type: [ResultObject].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

The other way I mentioned is to make the return type of the closure explicit. That's tricky because the return type is complex. You'll need to scroll to the right to see the whole thing:

```
func performSearch0(_ searchTerm: String) -> AnyPublisher<[ResultObject], Error> {
    return getValueKey().flatMap { value -> Publishers.Decode<Publishers.Map<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher, Data>, [ResultObject], JSONDecoder> in
        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.test.com/\(value)")!)
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [ResultObject].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

So when we choose this solution, we usually want to use `eraseToAnyPublisher` to simplify the type:

```
func performSearch1(_ searchTerm: String) -> AnyPublisher<[ResultObject], Error> {
    return getValueKey().flatMap { value -> AnyPublisher<[ResultObject], Error> in
        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.test.com/\(value)")!)
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [ResultObject].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher() /* Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such an amazingly complete answer!